# Page transition effects in flash

Tags: actionscript, flash

What are possible ways to implement page transition effects in flash?
e.g. page turning.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for flip book you should find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Different type of Flash transition effect for Movie Clip
Article: Adobe Flash Action Script 3.0.

Please visit the following link for all transition effect with example.

http://nexussoftwaregroup.com/articles/flash/TransitionEffect.aspx